# How to write "x is a composite number" using predicate logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I know that a composite number is a number formed by multiplying 2 smaller natural numbers. I think that will definitely be incorporated in the predicate somehow. I am really confused on how to represent this using predicate logic/logical connectives

Comment: Your first sentence is the key.  Try to translate that into a logical sentence.  Going by approximation is a good approach.  "2 smaller" suggests "there exists $a$ and there exists $b$ such that..."  Can you go from there?

Answer (score 2):

> So I know that a composite number is a number formed by multiplying 2 smaller natural numbers.

In other words, you are saying that "$x$ is a composite number" means exactly that:

- "There are two things which are both natural numbers, each smaller than $x$, and whose product equals $x$."

> I am really confused on how to represent this using predicate logic/logical connectives

Here are the symbols you will need: $x, n, m, \Bbb N, \exists, \in, <, =, \times, (,)$.

Just place them into a well formed formula that says what you need to say.

Answer (score 0):

$$\exists \{ y, z \}\ {\rm s.t.}\ (yz = x) \wedge (y < x \wedge z < x)\ {\rm for}\ \{ x, y, z \} \in \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: @PM 2Ring... umm... why not just edit that obvious typo yourself and be done with it?

Comment: Some people get annoyed by edits on fresh posts, especially if they're in the middle of expanding an initial short answer. But if it doesn't bother you, I'm happy to fix it myself, if I spot another obvious typo.